# How do I access core-ajax response data via javascript?

Tags: javascript, polymer

For instance, if I have the following code in an auto-binding template inside my index.html file:

**index.html**

```
<template is="auto-binding">
    <core-ajax id="ds" auto url="url/to/data.json" response="{{data}}"></core-ajax>
    <my-items items="{{data}}"></my-items>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        var responseData = ????
    });
})(wrap(document));
```

Comment: is this in a polymer element or just on the main html file? what do you plan to do with the response use it in html or javascript?

Comment: The code above is in the main HTML file, inside an auto-binding template.  I'm planning to use the data with javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically we use data binding with core-ajax, but if you need to get at it with JS you can either get the response out of the `core-response` event that `core-ajax` fires, or you can look at the `response` property of the `core-ajax` tag itself. [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/nelil/2/edit)

```
<core-ajax auto url="http://date.jsontest.com"></core-ajax>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var ajax = document.querySelector('core-ajax');
    ajax.addEventListener('core-response', function(e) {
      console.log(e.detail.response);
      // or
      console.log(e.target.response);
      // or
      console.log(ajax.response);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**edit: OP wants to get at a core-ajax element inside an auto binding template**

You should listen for the `template-bound` event fired by the `auto-binding` template when it stamps its content to the page. Then you can `querySelector` for `core-ajax`. [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/favume/11/edit)

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <core-ajax auto url="http://date.jsontest.com"></core-ajax>
</template>

<script>
  var tmpl = document.querySelector('template');
  tmpl.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
    var ajax = document.querySelector('core-ajax');
    ajax.addEventListener('core-response', function(e) {
      console.log(e.detail.response);
      // or
      console.log(e.target.response);
      // or
      console.log(ajax.response);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**edit: To show a nicer approach**

Since the original poster was specifically asking about getting the response using JavaScript, I gave the fully JS approach. You can clean this up quite a bit using bindings. [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/tinapi/1/edit)

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <core-ajax auto
             response="{{data}}"
             on-core-response="{{ajaxHandler}}"
             url="http://date.jsontest.com"
             handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
  <h1>{{data.date}}: {{data.time}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  addEventListener('template-bound', function(e) {
    // do something else with response
    e.target.ajaxHandler = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.response);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: try getting core-ajax by id var ajax = document.querySelector("#ds");

Comment: ajax is still null :(

Comment: Did you get that error from the JSBin example? It's working fine for me in Chrome. Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Worked great in jsbin.  I'm using chrome. I updated my original question with more context in case I'm doing something wrong elsewhere.